Load and navigating to next screen not working when coming back to screen
I have one SWiftUI application in which I have four screens. In Screen 3 I am calling an API and when I receive a response it is navigating to the next screen. This works perfectly when the user goes from Screen 1-> 2->3->4. But when coming back from 4->3 or  4->3->2->3, the API is called but the loader is not displayed and also not navigating to next screen. WHen I again go back to the first screen and do the same thing it works fine again. In short it is not working while navigating back. Only working for next. What can be the issue here?
struct Blur: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemMaterial

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}



struct SuccessView: View {
    
    @State private var image: UIImage?

    
    @State private var isProgressActive = false 
    @State private var isProgressCompleted = true 

    @State private var progress: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var next: Bool = false
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = GetImageViewModel()

    @State var isImageReceived : Bool = false

    @State var isFromBack : Bool = false


    @State var loaderCount : Int = 0
    init() {

    }

    var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    let screenWidth = geometry.size.width
                    let screenHeight = geometry.size.height
                    
                    // Background image
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        if let image = image {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Image(uiImage: image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            
                        } else {
                            // Text("No image available")
                            Image("profile")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    .background(Color.themegray)
                    
                    // Color overlay at the bottom
                    Color.themeBlur.opacity(0.9)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    // Content on top of the blurred image
                    VStack {
                        HeaderView(isBack: true, isRightButton: false, title: "Hola Amigos", isTitle: false, headerColor: .clear, backColor: .white)
                        
                        ScrollView(.vertical) {
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Spacer()
                                            .frame(height: 20)
                                        
                                        Text("Success")
                                        //.font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
                                            .font(Font.interDisplay(.semiBold, size: 24))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        Spacer()
                                            .frame(height: 10)
                                        
                                        Text("From now on you can use your ")
                                            .font(Font.interDisplay(.regular, size: 16))
                                        
                                        //.font(.system(size: 16))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                        Spacer()
                                            .frame(height: 10)
                                        
                                        Text("face to do things quicker")
                                            .font(Font.interDisplay(.regular, size: 16))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                        
                                        
                                        if isiPad()  {
                                            Spacer()
                                                .frame(height: 250)
                                        } else {
                                            Spacer()
                                                .frame(height: 80)
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                        //.frame(height: (screenHeight-500)/2)
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                       /* HStack  {
                                            SuccessAnimationView()
                                                .frame(width: 300,height: 300)
                                        }
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)*/
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                
                                //IF Animations
                               // Spacer()
                                 //   .frame(height: 110)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(height: 400)

                                
                                HStack {
                                    CustomButtonView(buttonClicked: {
                                        print("button clicked")
                                        self.next = true
                                      //  self.viewModel.showDetails = true
                                        
                                        
                                    }, title: "View Images")
                                    .isHidden(true
                                    )
                                   // .isHidden(!isImageReceived)
                                    /*.navigationDestination(isPresented: $route, destination: {
                                     // ContentView()
                                     })*/
                                }
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth-40)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $next, destination: {
                                    SelectImageView(outputImageArray: viewModel.outputImageArray)
                                        /*.onDisappear {
                                        
                                            // self.shouldResetProgress = true
                                            self.isFromBack = true
                                            print("on disappear called success",self.isFromBack)
                                        }*/

                                })
                                
                                
                                Spacer()
                                CustomProgressBar(progress: $progress, isProgressActive: $isProgressActive, isCompleted: $isProgressCompleted, progressBarCallback: {
                                    //  SelectImageView()
                                    self.next = true
                                    
                                    print("progress completed")
                                })
                                
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(height: 70)
                                /* .navigationDestination(isPresented: $next, destination: {
                                 SelectImageView()
                                 })*/
                                
                            }
                            .frame(height: geometry.size.height) // Match the height of ScrollView
                            //.background(Color.green)
                            
                        }
                        // .background(Color.green)
                    }
                 
                }
                .alert(item: $viewModel.loginError) { appAlert in
                    Alert(title: Text("\(StringConstants.Error)"),
                          message: Text("""
                            \(appAlert.errorString)
                            \(StringConstants.TryAgain)
                            """),
                          primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
                              // Handle OK button action here
                             // showAlert = false
                            // self.next  = true
                              print("next value",self.next)
                          }),
                          secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }

                 .overlay(
                  //  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    VStack {
                        BounceLoader()
                            .frame(width: 200,height: 200)
                            .isHidden(!viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader)
                           // .isHidden(!viewModel.shouldShow)

                        Text("Loader")
                            .isHidden(!viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader)
                           // .isHidden(!viewModel.shouldShow)

                    }

                    
                 )

                

                .onReceive(self.viewModel.$shouldDisplayLoader) { isShowing in
                    print("loader count in receive",self.loaderCount)
                    print("global loader in receive",viewModel.shouldShow)

                    if viewModel.shouldShow == true {
                        self.viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader = true
                        print("after value",self.viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader)
                    }
                    print("detail view isloader showing",isShowing)
                    self.loaderCount = self.loaderCount + 1
                    debugPrint(isShowing)
                    // Maybe do something here?
                }
                .onReceive(self.viewModel.$navigateToNextScreen) { navigateToNext in
                    print("navigate next success",navigateToNext)
                    debugPrint(navigateToNext)
                    if (navigateToNext == true) {
                        self.next = true
                    }
                    // Maybe do something here?
                }
                .onAppear{
                    
                    print("on appear called get image",self.isFromBack)
                    if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "image") {
                        self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        print("Image loaded from UserDefaults in onAppear")
                    }
                   // DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //isLoading = true

                   // }
                   // viewModel = GetImageViewModel()

                    viewModel.shouldShow = true
                    viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader = true
                    print("display loader",viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader)
                    print("display loader global",viewModel.shouldShow)

                  //  if self.isFromBack == false {
                        viewModel.getImage(completionAPI: {
                            self.isImageReceived = true

                            print("get image completetion")
                        })
                   // }
                    //  viewModel.getLocalResponse()
                    
                }


                .onDisappear {
                    
                    self.isFromBack = true
                   // viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader = false
                    self.loaderCount = 0
                    print("success disaaper called",viewModel.shouldDisplayLoader)
                }

                
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            }
        
    }
    
    
}


struct BlurredBackgroundView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SuccessView()
    }
}


#Preview {
    SuccessView()
}
//
//  LoginViewModel.swift

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Network

/*enum ViewStateToken {
    case START
    case LOADING
    case SUCCESS(tokenModel: Token)
    case FAILURE(error: String)
}*/

extension UIImage {
    func toBase64String() -> String {
        guard let imageData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else { return "" }
        return imageData.base64EncodedString()
    }
}



/*enum ViewStateLogin {
    case START
    case LOADING
    case SUCCESS(loginModel: PostUserImage)
    case FAILURE(error: String)
}*/

enum ViewStateGetImage {
    case START
    case LOADING
    case SUCCESS(loginModel: UserImage)
    case FAILURE(error: String)
}

class GetImageViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @AppStorage("isLogin")  var isLoginGlobal: Bool?
    @AppStorage("tokenName")  var tokenName: String?
    @AppStorage("tokenValue")  var tokenValue: String?

    struct LoginError: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        let errorString: String
        let errorCode: Int?
    }

    @Published var loginError: LoginError?
    var selectImageResponse: UserImage?
    @Published var showDetails = false

    

  //  let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
   // let monitorPostUser = NWPathMonitor()

    var monitorPostUser: NWPathMonitor?

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "InternetConnectionMonitor2")
    
    var version: String = "491ddf5be6b827f8931f088ef10c6d015f6d99685e6454e6f04c8ac298979686"

    var cancelable: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
  //  @Published var currentState: ViewStateToken = .START
 //   @Published var currentStateLogin: ViewStateLogin = .START
    
    @Published var currentStateGetImage: ViewStateGetImage = .START


    @Published var username: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    
    @AppStorage("getImageId")  var getImageId: String?

   // @Published var userNameValidator = UsernameValidation.emptyUsername
   // @Published var passwordValidator = PasswordValidation.empty
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    @Published var isLoginSuccess: Bool = false

    @Published var userNameError: String?
    @Published var passwordError: String?
    
      var image: UIImage?
     private var base64ImageString: String = ""
    
    var imageURL : String = ""
    
    private var outputImageString: String = ""
    var outputImage: UIImage?

    @AppStorage("outputImageArray") var outputImageArray: [String] = []

    private var getAPIStutus: String = "NotStarted"

    @Published  var shouldDisplayLoader : Bool = false
    @Published  var navigateToNextScreen : Bool = false


    @Published var loading = false

    @AppStorage("shouldShow") var shouldShow: Bool = false

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
       /* if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "image") {
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            print("Image loaded from UserDefaults in onAppear")
            
            if let image = self.image {
                self.base64ImageString = image.toBase64String()
                print("Base64 Image String: \(self.base64ImageString)")
            }
        }*/

    }

    ///  checks if loader should be displayed
    /// - Returns: should display loader or not
   /* func shouldHideLoader() -> Bool {
        if case .LOADING = currentStateLogin {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }*/

    func shouldHideLoaderGetImage() -> Bool {
        if case .LOADING = currentStateGetImage {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    

    
    func convertImageToBase64String (img: UIImage) -> String {
        return img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
    }

    func convertBase64StringToImage (imageBase64String:String) -> UIImage {
        let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageBase64String)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        return image!
    }

    /// PostImage  API Call
  /*  func postImage() {
        
       /* if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "image") {
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            print("Image loaded from UserDefaults in view model",self.image)
        }*/

        
        if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "image") {
            print("stored image data API call",imageData)
          //  self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            self.image = UIImage(named: "profile")

            print("Image loaded from UserDefaults in onAppear",self.image)
            
            if let image = self.image {
                self.base64ImageString = image.toBase64String()
                print("sent image is",image)
              //  self.base64ImageString = self.convertImageToBase64String(img: image)

               // let strBase64 =  image.pngData()?.base64EncodedString()
               // print("converted value",strBase64)
               // self.base64ImageString = strBase64 ?? ""
                print("Base64 Image String: \(self.base64ImageString)")

              //  print("Base64 Image String: \(self.base64ImageString)")
            }
        }
        
        
        let dummyInputData = APIParameters.InputData(
           // image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,<your_dummy_image_data_here>",
            image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,\(self.base64ImageString)",
            prompt: ". faded film, desaturated, 35mm photo, grainy, vignette, vintage, Kodachrome, Lomography, stained, highly detailed, found footage, masterpiece, best quality",
            scheduler: "EulerDiscreteScheduler",
            enable_lcm: false,
            pose_image: "https://replicate.delivery/pbxt/KJmFdQRQVDXGDVdVXftLvFrrvgOPXXRXbzIVEyExPYYOFPyF/80048a6e6586759dbcb529e74a9042ca.jpeg",
            num_outputs: 3,
            sdxl_weights: "protovision-xl-high-fidel",
            output_format: "png",
            pose_strength: 0.4,
            canny_strength: 0.3,
            depth_strength: 0.5,
            guidance_scale: 5,
            output_quality: 80,
            negative_prompt: "(lowres, low quality, worst quality:1.2), (text:1.2), watermark, painting, drawing, illustration, glitch, deformed, mutated, cross-eyed, ugly, disfigured (lowres, low quality, worst quality:1.2), (text:1.2), watermark, painting, drawing, illustration, glitch,deformed, mutated, cross-eyed, ugly, disfigured",
            ip_adapter_scale: 0.8,
            lcm_guidance_scale: 1.5,
            num_inference_steps: 30,
            enable_pose_controlnet: true,
            enhance_nonface_region: true,
            enable_canny_controlnet: false,
            enable_depth_controlnet: false,
            lcm_num_inference_steps: 5,
            controlnet_conditioning_scale: 0.8
        )


        APIConstants.basedURL = APIConstants.AVAURL
        APIConstants.isLogin = true
          self.currentStateLogin = .LOADING
        monitorPostUser.pathUpdateHandler = { pathUpdateHandler in
              if pathUpdateHandler.status == .satisfied {

                  APIClient.dispatch(
                  //  APIRouter.LoginRequest(body: APIParameters.LoginParams(userName:
                                                             //   self.username, password: self.password)))
                  
                    APIRouter.LoginRequest(body: APIParameters.ImageGenerationRequestParams(version: self.version, input: dummyInputData)))

                  .sink { completion in
                      switch completion {
                      case .finished:
                          print("Execution Finihsed Image select.")
                      case .failure(let error):
                          print("Image error description", error.localizedDescription)
                          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              self.currentStateLogin = .FAILURE(error: error.localizedDescription)
                              self.loginError = LoginError(errorString:
                                              error.localizedDescription, errorCode: error.errorCode)

                          }
                      }
                  }
              receiveValue: {  user in
                  print("received response login", user)
                  self.imageURL = user.input?.pose_image ?? ""

                 // self.imageURL = user.input?.pose_image ?? ""
                  self.outputImageString = user.input?.image ?? ""
                  print("output image string is",self.outputImageString)
                  
                //  self.outputImage = self.convertBase64StringToImage(imageBase64String: self.outputImageString)
                //  print("output image is",self.outputImage)
                //  print("Image from API is",self.imageURL)
                  
                 /* if user.authenticated == true {
                      self.isLoginSuccess = true
                      self.isLoginGlobal = true
                      self.resetData()

                  } else {
                      if let  errorMessage = user.message {
                          print("login error")
                          self.loginError = LoginError(errorString:
                                                        errorMessage, errorCode: 401)
                      }

                  }*/
                  
                  self.currentStateLogin = .SUCCESS(loginModel: user)
              }.store(in: &self.cancelable)

              } else {
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.currentStateLogin = .FAILURE(error: StringConstants.NoInterNet)
                      self.loginError = LoginError(errorString: StringConstants.NoInterNet, errorCode: 2000)
                    //  print("no internet login")
                  }
              }
          }
        monitorPostUser.start(queue: queue)
    }*/
    
    func getLocalResponse() {
        self.selectImageResponse = Bundle.main.decode("GetImageData.json")
        print("local select image is",self.selectImageResponse)

    }
    
    var isAPIcalled : Bool = false
    var count: Int = 0
    
    func getImage( completionAPI: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        
        self.loading = true

      //  self.shouldDisplayLoader = true
        monitorPostUser = NWPathMonitor()

        
        print("get image count",count)
        print("Get image start",self.shouldDisplayLoader)
      //  APIConstants.BaseURL = APIConstants.BaseURL
       // self.getImageId = "rvezj6pxp5rgm0cfazs98wn8mw"

        //Success id   = v3br26wpthrgm0cfav69pv1vy8
        //failed id = "fxsfwjksz9rgj0cfacnbf451ew"
        
      self.getImageId = "v3br26wpthrgm0cfav69pv1vy8"
        
        
        
       // self.getImageId = "fxsfwjksz9rgj0cfacnbf451ew"
        
       // print("actual imag eid is",self.getImageId)

        
       // APIConstants.isLogin = true
          self.currentStateGetImage = .LOADING
        monitorPostUser?.pathUpdateHandler = { pathUpdateHandler in
              if pathUpdateHandler.status == .satisfied {

                  APIClient.dispatch(
                  //  APIRouter.LoginRequest(body: APIParameters.LoginParams(userName:
                                                             //   self.username, password: self.password)))
                  
                    
                    APIRouter.GetImageRequest(getImageId: self.getImageId ?? ""))

                  .sink { completion in
                      switch completion {
                      case .finished:
                          print("Execution Finihsed Image select.")
                      case .failure(let error):
                          print("Image error description", error.localizedDescription)
                          DispatchQueue.main.async {

                              self.currentStateGetImage = .FAILURE(error: error.localizedDescription)
                              self.loginError = LoginError(errorString:
                                              error.localizedDescription, errorCode: error.errorCode)
                              completionAPI?()
                              self.navigateToNextScreen = true

                          }
                      }
                  }
              receiveValue: {  user in
                  print("received response getImage", user)
                //  print("user result",user.results)
                 /* for result in user.results ?? [] {
                      if let output = result.output {
                          print("Output URLs:",output)
                          for url in output {
                              print(url)
                              self.outputImageArray?.append(url)
                          }
                      }
                  }*/
                 // print("output imagearray",self.outputImageArray)
                  

                  self.outputImageArray = []
                  print("output imagearray count before is",self.outputImageArray.count)

                  self.outputImageArray = user.output ?? []
                  print("output imagearray",self.outputImageArray)

                  print("output imagearray count is",self.outputImageArray.count)
                 // if  self.outputImageArray.count > 0 {

                  if  self.outputImageArray.count > 0 {
                      print("Hide loader get image")
                  }
                  
                  self.getAPIStutus = user.status ?? "ErrorDummy"
                  print("get API status is",self.getAPIStutus)

                //  if self.getAPIStutus != "succeeded" && self.getAPIStutus != "failed" {

                  if self.getAPIStutus == "succeeded" && self.getAPIStutus != "failed" {
                      print("API called second time")
                     // self.currentStateGetImage = .LOADING
                     // DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
                     // if (self.isAPIcalled == false) {
                      
                      if (self.count < 2) {
                          //print("Actual API call")
                          self.count = self.count + 1

                          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
                              self.getImage()
                          }

                      }
                    else {
                          print("API received  dummy image")
                         // self.shouldDisplayLoader = false
                          self.navigateToNextScreen = true
                      }
                      //}
                  } else {
                      print("API received image")

                      completionAPI?()
                      self.navigateToNextScreen = true
                      self.shouldShow = false

                  }
                  
                  
                  
                  self.currentStateGetImage = .SUCCESS(loginModel: user)
              }.store(in: &self.cancelable)

              } else {
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.currentStateGetImage = .FAILURE(error: StringConstants.NoInterNet)
                      self.loginError = LoginError(errorString: StringConstants.NoInterNet, errorCode: 2000)
                      self.navigateToNextScreen = true
                  }
              }
          }
        monitorPostUser?.start(queue: queue)
    }


    func resetData() {
        self.cancellableSet = []
    }


}


change @ObservedObject var viewModel = GetImageViewModel() to @StateObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()
